# Using an already initialized object when performing a BUTTON action

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making this simple turn-based "Mortal Kombat" game. There are 2 comboBoxes from which you can choose some characters. When clicking on the attack button there's a semi-random Attack value generated, The HP of the opponent is reduced with that attack value. The person that first reaches 0 HP looses.

I am making 2 instances of the class Character (retrieved from the comboBoxes). The 2 instances are made when the attack-button is clicked. The problem is that every time that the user clicks on ATTACK, the 2 instances are made again, and therefore the HP gets reset to the default value. Character consists of Name, HealthPoints, Damage.

```
private void button_Attack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Character P1 = (Character)comboBox_CharacterSelectionP1.SelectedItem;
    Character P2 = (Character)comboBox_CharacterSelectionP2.SelectedItem;
    double HP_1;
    double HP_2;
    double DMG_1 = P1.Attack();
    double DMG_2 = P2.Attack();
    if (P1.Counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        HP_1 = P1.HealthPoints;
        HP_2 = P2.HealthPoints;
        label_Player1_HP.Text = HP_1.ToString();
        label_AttackValueP1.Text = DMG_1.ToString();
        label_Message.Text = $"{P1.Name} throws a punch";

        HP_2 -= DMG_1;
        label_Player2_HP.Text = HP_2.ToString();

        P1.Counter++;
    }
    else { //... }
}
```

I must create the 2 instances outside the attack button space. Where do I declare and initialize them in order to use them inside the attack-function? (=> so that the HP doesn't get reset every time that the user clicks on the attack-button)

The 2 instances are:

```
Character P1 = (Character)comboBox_CharacterSelectionP1.SelectedItem;
Character P2 = (Character)comboBox_CharacterSelectionP2.SelectedItem;
```

This is a picture of the Windows Forms App

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `Where do I declare and initialize them in order to use them inside the attack-function?` inside your class

Comment: I removed the forced tags from your question's title. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Comment: Your problem is caused not by the instances, you're not creating them in your method. You just don't store the new HP values in the players instances. The `HP_1` and `HP_2` variables are local.

Answer (score 0):

"Your problem is caused not by the instances, you're not creating them in your method. You just don't store the new HP values in the players instances. The HP_1 and HP_2 variables are local. – dymanoid"

This comment helped me out, thanks.

**My mistake** I made a local variables for the HP, which didn't update I suppose. Once I replaced those by the property HealthPoints of the class Character, it worked properly. New code looks as follows:

```
private void button_Attack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button_Play.Enabled = false;

        Character P1 = (Character)comboBox_CharacterSelectionP1.SelectedItem;
        Character P2 = (Character)comboBox_CharacterSelectionP2.SelectedItem;

        if (P1.Counter % 2 == 0)
        {
            double DMG_1 = P1.Attack();
            label_Player1_HP.Text = P1.HealthPoints.ToString("F3");
            label_AttackValueP1.Text = $"Damage inflicted: {DMG_1.ToString("F3")}";
            label_Message.Text = $"{P1.Name} throws a punch";

            P2.HealthPoints -= DMG_1;
            label_Player2_HP.Text = P2.HealthPoints.ToString("F3");

            P1.Counter++;
        }
        else...
```